# javascript up one folder

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of javascript:

```
  $.getJSON("something.json",function whatever(data)
```

Instead of putting `something.json` in the same folder as the javascript, I would like to move it one up in the directory structure.

How should I change the code to recognize the new location?

Comment: This will only work if the target location is still in your web root. If not, the server won't be able to serve the file.

Comment: My index.html is in my public folder and I am hoping to put the json file one above it for security.  Will this not work?

Comment: No. If you cannot access the file with an URL, it will not work. And normally you cannot go above the web root.

Comment: Is there a setting that can make it work?  I know with PHP files I can go up there... using ../

Comment: I don't think that is possible, that would be a huge security issue, as everyone could access all files on your server. Yes, PHP can do this, because it is running on the server and can directly access the file system. What you could do is creating a PHP file which reads the JSON file. But what's the point? The client will have access to the JSON data either way. I think your are making things too complicated. Any data which should be transferred between a server and a client is publicly accessible (if it does not require authorization). That's the way it is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The same way as for any other [relative URI](http://www.iusmentis.com/technology/www/relativeurls/).

```
../something.json
```